# How to pass keyboard shortcut to command prompt using powershell script

Tags: powershell, automation, keyboard-shortcuts, orchestration

[image]

I need to enter Ctrl-Y here using PowerShell script, in order to automate this task. please let me know how this can be done.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^y')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it is a way to send shortcuts in C#, but I am looking something for powershell scripts

Comment: did you try it in PowerShell ^^ Windows is a funny thing when it comes to VB and C ;)